# Alternative to Constants.h in swift

Tags: ios, swift

With Objective C, I used 'FileName.h' header file to declare all constants values with #default and it can be accessed from any other classes by importing the constants.h file.

In Swift: 
What is the alternate to that in swift?

Comment: in swift use .swift file

Comment: @DánielNagy. If i create a struct for that, is it possible to access from other classes?

Comment: @SARANGA , yes, you can access those from other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Constants.swift file. Following file will help you.
eg.:

```
class Constants: NSObject 
{
    static let msg = ""
    static let text = ""
}
```

Comment: how to call it from other swift files?

Comment: Ah, same answer in the same second. :-) You just use them like this: `Constant.msg` or similar.

Comment: Hi @Flovdis, & Bhagyalaxmi... Working.... Without static keyword it was not working. Thanks!

Comment: Which one need to be mark as an answer?

Comment: @BhagyalaxmiPoojary You should remove the `NSObject` superclass. It is not needed and generates unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Flovdis, Thanks for the suggestion :) I will surely try it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class somewhere which only has static variables.

```
class Constant {
    static let a = "demo1"
    static let b = "demo2"
}
```

Comment: How to call it from other swift files?